# Extra values not updating in pendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I have below code creating from service for notification.
I am trying to send different values in extra still getting the last set value every time in receiver.

```
Intent closeButton = new Intent(this,DownloadCancelReceiver.class);
closeButton.putExtra("id",id);
closeButton.setAction("Action"+Long.toString(id));
PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, closeButton, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

notificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_view);
notificationView.setProgressBar(R.id.pb_progress, 100, 5, false);
notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_close, pendingSwitchIntent);
```

Comment: you probably need to change that id each time

Comment: @Onheiron   I am changing id each time

Answer (score 9):

The only things that you are changing in Pending Intent are Extra and Action, and then for optimization purposes Android is reusing the old intent. Try to change PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT with PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT

To create the PendingIntent try:

```
PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, closeButton, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```